# Strange Python Scope Issue

Tags: python, scope

I thought that I understood Python variable scope pretty well, but then I ran into this code today.

```
from __future__ import print_function

def main():
    v_Matrix =[[1, 2, 3],
               [4, 5, 6],
               [7, 8, 9]]

    print(v_Matrix)
    print()

    f_Rotate(v_Matrix)
    print(v_Matrix)

    hh = 3
    f_This(hh)
    print(hh)

def f_Swap(v_Matrix, r1, c1, r2, c2):
    v_Matrix[r1][c1], v_Matrix[r2][c2] = v_Matrix[r2][c2], v_Matrix[r1][c1]

def f_Transpose(v_Matrix):
    for row in range(len(v_Matrix)):
        for col in range(row):
            f_Swap(v_Matrix, row, col, col, row)

def f_FlipVertical(v_Matrix):
    v_Size = len(v_Matrix)
    for row in range(v_Size // 2):
        for col in range(v_Size):
            f_Swap(v_Matrix, row, col, v_Size - row - 1, col)

def f_Rotate(v_Matrix):
    f_Transpose(v_Matrix)
    f_FlipVertical(v_Matrix)

def f_This(hh):
    hh = hh * 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When run, the variable `v_Matrix` seems to behave as if global. However, the test variable `hh` behaves as expected with one scope in `main()` and the other in `f_This`.

`v_Matrix` is not global, is modified in various functions, but is not passed back and forth between those functions, or even returned to `main()`. Yet the value changes applied to `v_Matrix` in those functions are accessible in the `main()` scope as seen between the outputs. However, as expected, the value of the test variable `hh` does not change in the `main()` scope, only in the scope of the function.

What gives?

Comment: That's because lists are mutable. See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types for a detailed discussion.

Comment: And Python passes a pointer to a mutable object as a parameter when calling function, rather than creating a copy of the object.  As with C-style pointers, you can modify the contents of the object that is pointed to, but cannot cause the caller of the function to point to a new object by assigning it.

Comment: @Selcuk Okay, not much was mentioned as to scope in your link. However, your comment did help point me toward the fact that mutable objects, especially lists have a different behavior as to scope based upon "outer," vs "inner" containers, etc. I don't yet understand it all, but I will. I guess I missed that fact when I studied scope.Thanks.

Comment: @ Matt Jordan Thanks to your comment and Selcuk's I'm getting a handle on it. I was lost, now I'm found. Thanks.

Comment: @JayJay123, mutable and immutable objects do not have a different behavior based on scope.  They are passed to functions in the exact same way.  It's just that mutable objects can be changed in place, while immutable objects can't.  `hh=hh*2` for example, doesn't mutate the existing integer object containing 3, but reassigns the local `hh` named  to another integer object containing 6.  The outer `hh` name still refers to 3.  For the matrix, there is an outer and inner variable named `v_Matrix` assigned to a list, and the list object is changed in place.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen Yes, that seems to be what I am learning. I had no idea that things worked that way. I thought scope was scope and not affected by container/type. Now I know. Thanks.

Comment: @JayJay123, scope *is* scope.  You have separate `v_Matrix` names that exist locally in each function, they just happen to all reference the same mutable object.  Mutate the object through one local name and they all appear to change. `hh` in main() and f_this() are separate names that initially refer to the same immutable integer, but f_this() reassigns its local `hh` to another integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list` is a mutable data structure. What it means is you can change its value while keeping the `id()` same. if you are passing around a variable which *names* such an object, as it has the same `id` it is the same object you are referring to in various parts of the code. So if you change it anywhere it's mutated for good.

So the solution is, **don't pass them around**. Rather *keep* it and *use* it in data transformations (not mutation) i.e create another one or better yet use generators and only evaluate the final required list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and info.

Answer (score 2):

Everything in Python is an object, and objects are passed to functions the same way whether they are mutable or immutable.  Changes to mutable objects can, however, be seen outside the function.

Example:

```
def f(c,d):
    print('Inside f()')
    print('  id(a) =',id(a),'value =',a)
    print('  id(b) =',id(b),'value =',b)
    print('  id(c) =',id(c),'value =',c)
    print('  id(d) =',id(d),'value =',d)
    c = 4     # local name c is assigned a new object.
    d[0] = 5  # local name d's object is mutated
    print('  id(a) =',id(a),'value =',a)
    print('  id(b) =',id(b),'value =',b) # b and d objects are same, so b changed
    print('  id(c) =',id(c),'value =',c) # id changed, not same as a
    print('  id(d) =',id(d),'value =',d) # id did not change, still same as b
    d = [6]   # local name d is assigned a new object.
    print('  id(d) =',id(d),'value =',d) # id changed, not same as b 
a = 3 # immutable
b = [3] # mutable
print('Before f()')
print('  id(a) =',id(a),'value =',a)
print('  id(b) =',id(b),'value =',b)
f(a,b)
print('After f()')
print('  id(a) =',id(a),'value =',a)
print('  id(b) =',id(b),'value =',b)
```

Annotated Output:

```
Before f()
  id(a) = 507107264 value = 3
  id(b) = 67001608 value = [3]
Inside f()
  id(a) = 507107264 value = 3
  id(b) = 67001608 value = [3]
  id(c) = 507107264 value = 3    # id(c) == id(a)
  id(d) = 67001608 value = [3]   # id(d) == id(b)
  id(a) = 507107264 value = 3
  id(b) = 67001608 value = [5]   # id(d)==id(b), so b changed when d did
  id(c) = 507107296 value = 4    # c was reassigned, id(c) != id(a)
  id(d) = 67001608 value = [5]   # id(d) == id(b)...object mutated
  id(d) = 65761864 value = [6]   # d was reassigned, id(d) != id(b)
After f()
  id(a) = 507107264 value = 3    # immutable a unaffected
  id(b) = 67001608 value = [5]   # sees mutation of list contents from d[0]=5
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.